# Positive definite and hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

Let $H$ be quaternion space. Let $A\in M_{n}(H)$. Then $A$ is hermitian i.e, $A^{*}=A$ if and only if $A$ is positive-definite i.e, $x^{*}Ax$ is real and positive for every nonzero $x\in H^{n}$. 
How can I prove it?

Comment: Hint : Every eigenvalue of a Hermitian matrix is real. Now use the criterion for definiteness using the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a Hermitian matrix. The eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are always positive. See if you can proceed here in the forward direction. For the other direction, let $x^*Ax$ be positive definite. Think about how you can show that the $x^*A^*x$ is equal to $x^*Ax$, given that the solution is positive definite.

Comment: $-I$ is a Hermitian matrix which does not have positive eigenvalues.